# How to exclude a set of data from matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, curve

I've a Matrix A (319 rows*26 cols) and two vectors that represent an upper_bound (319,1) ,  and a lower_bound (319,1)?
My goal is to check if among a set of 26 curves (319 point for each curve) there are some point greater or lower than upper_bound / lower bound curve in order to exclude a particular set of data if there is at least one point that pass these limits. 
I've tried with find() function to get the index value but without success. I've got too many data..Maybe I'm wrong managing data matrix..
Thanks in advance.
L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create a logical matrix with `true` for values inside bounds is using `bsxfun`

```
>> inBounds = bsxfun( @ge, A, lowerBound ) & bsxfun( @le, A, upperBound );
```

I used `ge` (greater-equal) and `le` (less than-equal) but you can use `gt` (greater than) and/or `lt` (less than) operators for the comparison.

Comment: thanks, works very well, but in order to get directly the values row by row?.I've always the problem to manage data inside cell array when I try to apply the chauvenet's criterion to reject data from the entire A matrix.

Comment: @user2761744 once you have `inBounds` logical matrix you can use `find` on it the same way you used it on `A > 20` in your previous question

Comment: Ok,I got a cell array 'p' with all the indices. Now I'd like to obtain another cell array 't' with all the original values of A referred to these particular indices. I've done it with a for cycle, but it needs too much time. Do you know a faster way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2761744 - new questions, post as questions and not as comments.